# scipy.stats.norm for array of values with different accuracy in different method

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

Generate two arrays:

```
np.random.seed(1)
x = np.random.rand(30, 2)
np.random.seed(2)
x_test = np.random.rand(5,2)
```

Caluclate scipy.stats.norm axis by axis:

```
gx0 = scipy.stats.norm(np.mean(x[:,0]), np.std(x[:,0])).pdf(x_test[:,0])
gx1 = scipy.stats.norm(np.mean(x[:,1]), np.std(x[:,1])).pdf(x_test[:,1])
```

and get:

```
gx0 = array([1.29928091, 1.1344507 , 1.30920536, 1.10709298, 1.26903949])
gx1 = array([0.29941644, 1.36808598, 1.13817727, 1.34149231, 0.95054596])
```

Calculate using NumPy broadcasting

```
gx = scipy.stats.norm(np.mean(x, axis = 0), np.std(x, axis = 0)).pdf(x_test)
```

and get:

```
gx = array([[1.29928091, 0.29941644],
       [1.1344507 , 1.36808598],
       [1.30920536, 1.13817727],
       [1.10709298, 1.34149231],
       [1.26903949, 0.95054596]])
```

gx[:,0] and gx0 look like the same, but subtracting one from another `gx[:,0] - gx0` will get:

```
array([-4.44089210e-16, -2.22044605e-16, -4.44089210e-16,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00])
```

Why is that?

Comment: Remove the call of `norm.pdf` and look closely at its *inputs*.    For example, I get `np.mean(x[:,1])` is `0.5190042819207465` but `np.mean(x, axis = 0)[1]` is `0.5190042819207463`.  (That's with an older version of numpy (1.20.3) that I happened to have running in an ipython session.)

Comment: See https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/20684

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why they calculate the answer to different precisions, but converting the input arrays to 128 bit floats solves the problem:

```
np.random.seed(1)
x = np.random.rand(30, 2).astype(np.float128)
np.random.seed(2)
x_test = np.random.rand(5,2).astype(np.float128)
```

...

```
print(gx[:,0] - gx0)
```

results in:

```
[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You may check the link: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/20684 provided above by Warren Weckesser